# Why aren't my instances of ObjectInput/OutputStrem creating?

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm learning about sockets and I was making a short example on how to send serializable objects through java sockets. The issue is that when I instance both of the input and output streams (`ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`). The program won't continue it's course.
I want to exchange an object from the class `User` I have created in both server and client.

This is my server program:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3333);

        Socket client = server.accept();

        ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("Instances created");     //Doesn't print on execution

        User user = (User)objectInput.readObject();
        System.out.println(user.toString());

        client.close();
        server.close();
    }
}
```

And this is the client program:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket server = new Socket("here I wrote my IP", 3333);
        User user = new User("Me", "me@gmail.com", 20);

        ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("Instances created");    //Doesn't print on execution

        objectOutput.writeObject(user);

        server.close();
    }
}
```

When I execute the server then the client, both of the programs keep executing but nothing shows on the console. Not even the `System.out.println("Instances created");`.

Why? Am I doing something wrong?

If you are wondering, class User looks like this:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int edad;

    public User (String name, String email, int edad) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " (" + email + "), " + edad + " años";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use Java Serializations as [it is dangerous](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#8).

The `ObjectInputStream` will block trying to read the header on both client and server. You should be able to see this from the stack traces.

Comment: So all I should do is wait till `ObjectInputStream` reads the headers? Also thanks for the advice on Java Serializations